# ERROR : fetching data from mysql and showing in on the web

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

  $user = 'root';
  $password = 'root';
  $db = 'urls';
  $host = 'localhost';
  $port = 8889;

  $link = mysqli_init();
  $success = mysqli_real_connect(
     $link, 
     $host, 
     $user, 
     $password, 
     $db,
     $port
  );

  //echo $success;

  $query = "SELECT id, title, url, votes FROM link ORDER BY id LIMIT 3";

  $result = mysqli_query($success, $query);

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["title"], $row["url"]);

  /* free result set */
  mysqli_free_result($result);

  /* close connection */
  mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

So this is the code i wrote. Obviously, the purpose of this is to fetch latest datas from my mysql server and print it out. However, when i run this code on my mac(I'm using MAMP), IT ONLY SHOW '0'. What is wrong with this?

Comment: What about checking `mysqli_connect_error()`

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_real_connect` returns a boolean, it does not return a MySQLi resource. Hence you have to run the query on `$link` and not on `$success`

```
$result = mysqli_query($success, $query);
                       ^
```

Should be

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Without any error checking in place it becomes like a guessing game, please consider error checking whether the connection resulted in an error or the query itself, that will help you a long way.

Also note that you have to either fetch all the rows together in one call (using a different function as to what you use now) or you have to loop through the result to fetch all the rows, with your current code you will get only 1 row at max even when the issue is resolved.

On another note, why are you not using the simpler `mysqli_connect` option and using this 2 step connection without any special flags being used?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a bit more error handling

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'urls';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', filemtime(__FILE__)), "\r\n";

$link = mysqli_init();
if ( !mysqli_real_connect($link, $host, $user, $password, $db, $port) ) {
    trigger_error('connect failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT id, title, url, votes FROM link ORDER BY id LIMIT 3";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query); // <- you have to pass the connection resource/object here
    if ( !$result ) {
        trigger_error('query failed', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if ( !$row ) {
            echo 'no results';
        }
        else {
            do {
                printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["title"], $row["url"]);
            } while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        }
        /* free result set */
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    /* close connection */
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

( the echo date... line is for checking that you're looking at the output of your latest and greatest script version ;-) )

Comment: Such a nice answer. One small thing however, that fetch has to be in a loop. Currently it will fetch only 1 row.

Comment: ah, you're right  Hanky 웃 Panky . I answered in auto-mode ;-)

Comment: btw: adding the do-while loop triggered my "too deeply nested" aesthetics alarm ;-) But I guess it doesn't help the OP to transform the original script even more.

Comment: Even with this updated code it's not working properly. _mysqli_fetch_array()_ function still displays nothing.

Comment: You did get the date output and absolutely nothing else?

Comment: yes, this is the output you would get when you run this code, `2015-11-10 21:38:55 () () () `

Comment: Looks like the record contains either empty strings or null values. `var_export($row);` instead of the printf line might tell. But either way I don't think that it's a problem with fetching the data but the INSERT failed.

Comment: How do you know all that Rajdeep Paul?

Comment: And no that is not the output this code will produce. It is impossible for it to print those 3 braces pairs at the end. So currently there is no reason to believe this code is *not working properly*

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, I've run this code on my machine, and this is the output I'm getting `2015-11-10 21:38:55 () () () `, Those three braces are being printed because of this print statement `printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["title"], $row["url"]);`, I'm not quite sure how or why. But when I added _DESC_ after _ORDER BY_ clause in the query statement it worked fine. Would you please run the code on your system and see what output are you getting?

Comment: That's because `\n` is not a `<br>`, run it with a `<pre>` tag. Secondly this suggests that your test data doesn't have `title` and `url` fields populated. Yes you are right that DESC order is needed but that doesn't invalidate this code. Its good

Comment: I still think that the first three records have empty title and url fields. The last three have proper values.